# Get the page token of current page using google youtube search api

Tags: youtube-javascript-api

I am using [Youtube search api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) for my application. I want to allow user to jump to a specific page number. I know there is something called firstPageToken and prevPageToken we get in the response. But how to retrieve the pageToken of specific page at specific count?

Any help will be appreciating.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Youtube API only provides NextPageToken and PreviousPageToken, that's it, sorry: see documentation here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list

You can still make a pagination item but you will have to implement it by calling multiple times the URL, passing the NextPageToken as pageToken in your requestion every time, and caching results.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is little difficult when we have to jump on to the last page.

Answer (score 0):

I've posted a solution for generating your own page tokens. I've only tested it for playlistItems, but it may be of some use.

[Youtube Data API v3 pageToken for arbitrary page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30949556/youtube-data-api-v3-pagetoken-for-arbitrary-page)